# how to load python3 to eric IDE?

Tags: 12.04, python3

Installed Eric IDE for python 3 Learning by using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS .

But Eric showing Python2.7.3 , not showing python 3 even its installed . so how can i configure Eric to show the python as python3 .

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we got Eric 4 that's suitable for python 2 and Eric 5 is the IDE for python 3 . 
so we need to install ERIC 5 to load python 3 .

Answer (score 0):

To install eric5 for python 3:

:~/eric5-5.x.x$ sudo python3 install.py

Note: Probably best to remove original attempt first before second install. Take a look in original extracted/unpacked file folder and run uninstall.py Once uninstall.py runs, type the "locate" command to see if it removed the files.